# What is the square root of the quadratic form $x^T A x$?

Tags: matrices, radicals, quadratic-forms

If $x \in \mathbb R^N$ and $A \in \mathbb R^{N \times N}$, is it possible to find a root of the quadratic form $x^T A x$ of the form $$\sqrt{x^T A x} = b^T x$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^N$, where $b \in \mathbb R^N$?

Comment: In general, $\sqrt{x^\top A x}$ cannot be expressed as $b^\top x$ for some vector $b$. For instance with $A$ being the identity matrix, the left-hand side is $\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_N^2}$ which is not a linear combination of $x_1, \ldots, x_N$.

Comment: You should restrict your attention to symmetric, positive semidefinite matrices. The non-symmetric part of $A$ contributes nothing to the quadratic form, and if $A$ is not positive semidefinite, you will be taking square roots of negative numbers.

Answer (score 7):

If the matrix $\bf A$ is symmetric, positive semidefinite and rank-$1$, then there exists a vector $\bf v$ such that ${\bf A} = {\bf v} {\bf v}^\top$ and, thus,

$$\sqrt{ {\bf x}^\top {\bf A} \, {\bf x}} = \sqrt{ {\bf x}^\top {\bf v} {\bf v}^\top {\bf x}} = \sqrt{ \left( {\bf v}^\top {\bf x} \right)^2} = \left| {\bf v}^\top {\bf x} \right|$$

which is not *exactly* what you desired, merely close to it.

---

[matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [rank-1-matrices](/questions/tagged/rank-1-matrices)

Comment: I really hoped that there was no general solution, but having a condition for that is also useful.